# PHPExcel HTML reader not accepting any html files, returns <file> is an Invalid HTML file

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I tried loading a lot of different html files but even those generated trough PHPExcel's own writer returned the same error. I've confirmed the file is there and readable and will post the load code as well as the file below:

the php code i'm using:

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML();
$objPHPExcel = @$objReader->load($file_path.'fisier_test.html');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="ExportProduseOportunitati.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

And I've pasted the HTML in this jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4wPza/). It won't look right because I kept the html and head tags and the css is included in the head, but I wanted to keep the html file intact so I'll leave it like that. (the file was created with PHPExcel)

I'm just trying to see if I can make PHPExcel work for converting HTML into XLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/203) has been raised and fixed in the develop branch on github.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Problem is, while it formats the table almost fine (ignores widths) anything except that isn't formatted at all. No bolds, links are wrong, no images... But that's for another time. The current issue has been fixed. Also no utf8

Comment: The HTML REader is pretty new, and first priority was simply to get it reading data: inline styling will come in time, and hopefully css thereafter... but unlikely to be this year

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens because of your file do not have permissions.

In Ubuntu try this.

```
chmod -R 777 myfile
```